# How to bind data to a DataGridView in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, desktop-application

I want to bind all information to a DataGridView.
I have debugged all program and it's completely working, just the data is not showing in the DataGridView.

```
public class Mobile
{
    public string id;
    public string title;
    public string price;
}


var mobiles = new List<Mobile>();
foreach (var ProductlistItems in ProductlistItem)
{   
    var mobile = new Mobile
    {
        id = ProductlistItems.GetAttributeValue("listingid", ""),

        title = ProductlistItems.Descendants("h3")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
             .Equals("lvtitle")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),

         price = (ProductlistItems.Descendants("li")
           .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
              .Equals("lvprice prc")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t')),
    };
    mobiles.Add(mobile);

}
dataGridView1.DataSource = mobiles;
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but databinding works with properties only.  `Mobile` uses public members not properties.  It also seems like you should be talking about the `DataGridView` if it is `Winforms`

Comment: Change your fields into public Properties: `public string id; => public string id { get; set; }`. Also,  `FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim(...)` is bound to fail.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow thank you very much now its working.

Comment: @Jimi yes I have changed my code as you suggested with the help of example now working my code thanks.no need to remove FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim(...).

Comment: I didn't suggest to remove it. But, since you're expecting null values, you may get them at some point. That code won't respond well. Test it with nulls and see what happens.